# Get nearby places from Google API sorted by distance

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I am currently stuck on this functionality where user need nearby places results on the basis of distance.

*For e.g :-
If i search "Kochi" and i am in India
Then kochi is in India as well as in Japan
So result should be like 
 1. Kochi, India
 2. Kochi, Japan*

This is just an example, user can also search landmarks, city, streets etc.. But i want all results to be sorted by distance.Closer results will display first and then far places. But not able to get results according to requirement.

Similar functionality is done on android and they are using it by passing radius (Like 500 km from current location)

What i have tried so far :-

- Using GMSPlacesClient.autocompleteQuery and passing bounds in it for current location

```html
GMSPlacesClient().autocompleteQuery(txtLocation.text!, bounds: bounds, filter: filter, callback: {(results, error) -> Void in
     if let error = error {
         print("Autocomplete error \(error)")
         return
     }
     if let results = results {
     }
})
```

- Using GooglePlaces.placeAutocomplete

```html
GooglePlaces.placeAutocomplete(forInput: self.txtLocation.text!, offset: 0, locationCoordinate: nil, radius: nil, language: nil, types: [GooglePlaces.PlaceType.Regions], components: nil, completion: { (response, error) in
       // To do                         
 })
```

- I also used this url (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=pan&location=30.704316,76.712106&radius=50000&components=country:IN) for Google API but for these kind of alternatives i have to do custom parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I am playing around with the same GoogleMaps API.  I do the same as you requested but through a different way code is attached, I do this on a button press for 'Search' you can either set the bounds to coordinates or the map view frame.  In the below it is currently using the users current location for the bounds and it then works its way out from that I think this works near enough perfectly:

```html
        let autoCompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autoCompleteController.delegate = self as! GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate
                
        // Set bounds to map viewable region
        let visibleRegion = googleMaps.projection.visibleRegion()
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: visibleRegion.farLeft, coordinate: visibleRegion.nearRight)
        
        // New Bounds now set to User Location so choose closest destination to user.
        let predictBounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: userLocation.coordinate, coordinate: userLocation.coordinate)
        
        autoCompleteController.autocompleteBounds = predictBounds
        
        // Set autocomplete filter to no filter to include all types of destinations.
        let addressFilter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        addressFilter.type = .noFilter
        
        autoCompleteController.autocompleteFilter = addressFilter
        
        // Change text color
        UISearchBar.appearance().setTextColor(color: UIColor.black)
                
        self.present(autoCompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am having a problem with Google Directions and getting the calculated distance and miles if you have any code for this that may be of help for me!